# Is it necessary that the maximal element of a topology be the underlying set of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition

**Edit:** This question has been rewritten, check the edit history for the original post.

Suppose that I want a completely formal first-order proof of some theorem in topology (doesn't matter which). Presumably, I would start by stating the [non-logical] axioms (those first order statements which do not require a proof) of topology, since any theorem will ultimately follow from these.

In analogy with abstract algebra, it is my impression that [general] topology may be regarded as the study of a particular class of structures, namely topological spaces.$^1$ And just as the basic properties of groups (the group axioms) form the basis of group theory, the basic properties of topological spaces serve, at least initially, as the axioms of topology.

The usual informal statement of the open-set definition of a topology goes something like this:

> Let $X$ be a set and $\tau$ a family of subsets of $X$, then the pair $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a topological space iff:
>
> 1. $\tau$ contains the empty set and $X$,
> 2. $\tau$ is closed under [arbitrary] union,
> 3. $\tau$ is closed under [finite] intersection.

Which can be formally stated as

1. $\emptyset,X\in \tau$
2. $\forall S\subseteq\tau.\bigcup S\in\tau$

   3a. $\forall x,y\in\tau.x\cap y\in\tau$

   3b. $\forall S\subseteq\tau.|S|<\aleph_0\implies\bigcap S\in\tau$

(the choice between 3a and 3b is a discussion for another time)

A somewhat natural question to ask is whether or not these represent the minimal axioms for topology and what, if anything, we might change without affecting existing results in topology. This brings me to my question. Suppose that $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a topological space. Is it necessary that $X$ be the maximal element of $\tau$?

---

**Note:** the following statements are equivalent$^2$

1. $X$ is the maximal element of $\tau$ (i.e. $\bigcup\tau=X$)
2. $\tau$ is a subset of the power set of $X$

(Proof in footnotes.)

---

At first, it might seem that the answer is an obvious "yes," but consider that a pair of sets $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ may satisfy each of the four listed requirements independently of whether or not $\bigcup\tau=X$.

In particular, it seems that if $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ and $X\subset Y$, then $\tau\cup \left\{Y\right\}$ is *also* a topology on $X$ - inasmuch as it preserves all topological properties of the space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$. That the underlying set of a space might then be any one of several elements of the topology would also justify the definition of a topological space being a *pair*, since the underlying set might differ from the maximal element of the topology.

If, however, it is required for any topological space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ that $\bigcup\tau=X$ then the statement of the underlying set is redundant. With only cosmetic changes to existing terminology and conventions, it becomes possible to disregard the notion of topological space entirely in favor of considering only the topology itself.

More significantly, if it is necessary that $\bigcup\tau=X$ for any topological space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$, then the axioms of topology can be stated as follows:

$\tau$ is a topology iff:

1. $\forall S\subseteq\tau.\bigcup S\in\tau$
2. $\forall S\subseteq\tau.|S|<\aleph_0\implies\bigcap S\in\tau$

From this, the underlying set of a topology $\tau$ is simply *defined* as the maximal element. Furthermore, we may prove that $\bigcup\tau\in\tau$ (a topology contains its underlying set as an element), $\emptyset\in\tau$, and the closed-set definition of a topology, with minimal effort.

In fact, it might even be possible to formalize all of topology with a *single* axiom.

---

$^1$ A topological space may be defined as a set with no additional structure, a pair of sets with no additional structure, a relational structure, or an algebraic structure.

$^2$ Theorem:

$X$ is the maximal element of $\tau$ if and only if $\tau$ is a subset of the powerset of $X$.

Proof:

The existence of a maximal element is guaranteed by closure under arbitrary union.

subproof 1:

Suppose that $\tau$ is a subset of the powerset of $X$ satisfying the listed axioms. By definition, every set $U\in\tau$ must then be a subset of $X$.

Suppose that $X$ is not the maximal element of $\tau$. Then there exists some set $U\in\tau$ such that $U$ is not a subset of $X$. Therefore, by contradiction, if $\tau\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ and all axioms hold, then $X$ is the maximal element of $\tau$

subproof 2:

Suppose that $\tau$ is a set containing $X$ as its maximal element and satisfying all listed axioms. By definition, every set $U\in\tau$ must then be a subset of $X$.

Suppose that $\tau$ is not a subset of the powerset of $X$. Then there exists some set $U\in\tau$ such that $U$ is not a subset of $X$. Therefore, by contradiction, if $X$ is the maximal element of $\tau$, then $\tau\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Therefore $\tau$ is a subset of the powerset of $X$ if and only if $X$ is the maximal element of $\tau$.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather state (4) as $\forall a\in\tau.\forall b\in \tau. a\cap b\in \tau$

Comment: @Gae.S. Any other recommendations?

Comment: @Gae.S. ... interesting question... "finite intersections" (including the intersection of the empty family) or "intersection of $2$ elements" (from which follows intersection of finite nonempty families).

Comment: I believe it is very much standard to speciy a topology on a set as a family of subsets. This is how it is done on wikipedia, in Kelley's Book, in Steen & Seebach's Counterexamples in Topology, and virtually every other text on topology I have ever seen

Comment: @GEdgar I mean, you *would* need an additional sentence to specify that you mean $\bigcap \emptyset=X$ anyways...

Comment: @G.Chiusole That would make sense, but for whatever reason the statement "is a family of subsets" is never listed with the other axioms.

Comment: @R.Burton It is usually given as "a topology on $X$ is a family of subsets of $X$ s.t. ...." followed by the 4 points you gave. I'm not entirely sure what your question is.

Comment: "Is never listed in the axioms" seems rather harsh.  For example, G.K. Pedersen's "Analysis Now" defines a topology as follows on pp.8: "A *topology on a set $X$* is a system $\tau$ **of subsets of $X$** with the properties that (i) every union of sets in $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$; (ii) every finite intersection of sets in $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$; (iii) $\varnothing\in \tau$ and $X\in \tau$". [emphasis added]

Comment: @R.Burton It's a similar situation to groups. There one says "A group is a set $G$ with binary function $f: G \times G \rightarrow G$ s.t. ..." and then listing the usual group axioms

Comment: Kelley's "General Topology"  says: "A *topology* is a family $\tau$ of sets which satisfies the two conditions: the intersection of any two members of $\tau$ is a member of $\tau$, and the union of themembers of each subfamily of $\tau$ is a member of $\tau$. The set $X=\cup\{U\mid U\in\tau\}$ is necessarily a member of $\tau$ because $\tau$ is a subfamily of itself, and every member of $\tau$ is a subset of $X$. The set $X$ is called the *space* of the topology $\tau$, and $\tau$ is a *topology for $X$*. The pair $(X,\tau)$ is a **topological space**." (pp. 37)

Comment: Bourbaki's "General Topology" book 1 says: "Definition 1. A topological structure (or more briefly, a topology) on a set $X$ is a structure given by a set $\tau$ of subset of $X$, having the following properties (called axioms of topological structures): every union of sets in $\tau$ is a set in $\tau$; every finite intersection of sets in $\tau$ is a set of $\tau$." It then goes on to note that taking the empty family in the first yields $\varnothing\in \tau$; and taking the intersection of the empty family in the second yields $X\in\tau$.

Comment: That's the three books on my shelves that define "topological space". All of them explicitly require the collection $\tau$ to be a collection of subsets of the set $X$.

Comment: You have asserted, without any supporting examples, that the statement "$\tau$ is a family of subsets of $X$" is never listed with the other axioms. Unless some examples are forthcoming to support your assertion, your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: The use of the term "axiom" in this context has _nothing_ to do with axioms in the foundational sense.  It's just an informal synonym for "conditions in a definition".

Comment: In other words, if you were to formalize topology in MetaMath, then _nothing_ here would be an axiom.  It would all just be definitions.

Comment: What you have is a **definition**. The “axioms”, as you call them, are the rules the defined object must meet. If you want to take them as axioms for a structure, **then the structure must satisfy the pre-amble of the definition before you start checking the axioms.** As such, you are just completely and utterly wrong in claiming that one does not require the collection of “open sets” to be a subset of the power set of the underlying space. **It is part of the structural definition of a topological space** Your examples don’t support your assertion, they **undermine it**.

Answer (score 5):

The following definitions are equivalent:

> A **widget** is a gadget $X$ such that
>
> - $X$ satisfies this property
> - $X$ satisfies that property
> - $X$ satisfies another property

and

> A **widget** is a thing $X$ such that
>
> - $X$ is a gadget
> - $X$ satisfies this property
> - $X$ satisfies that property
> - $X$ satisfies another property

It's not that $\tau \subseteq X$ isn't included as an axiom, it's just easier to say

> A topology on $X$ is a subset $\tau \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that
>
> ...etc...

than it is to say

> A topology is a thing $\tau$ such that
>
> - $\tau \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$
> - ...etc...

In particular, we'd never even ask if $(X, \tau)$ was a topology space if $\tau$ were not a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

By analogy, we don't usually include "$\star$ is a binary operation on $G$" as a separate axiom in group theory. We say a group is a pair $(G, \star)$ where $\star$ is a binary operation on $G$ such that [insert group axioms here].

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to be precise, you have to define a topological space explicitly as a *pair*: $(X, \mathcal{T})$ where $X$ is a set (I assume we're in ZFC so we know what that is) and $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$. These two facts could be called axiom (0), as it were.

The usual axioms then further state (there are at least two flavours possible for the finite intersection one):

- $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$.
- $X \in \mathcal{T}$.
- $\forall A,B \in \mathcal{T}: A \cap B \in \mathcal{T}$ or $\forall \mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{T}: |\mathcal{F}| < \aleph_0  \to \bigcap \mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{T}$
  ( I prefer the first as it's a bit simpler.)
- $\forall \mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{T}: \bigcup \mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{T}$

I seem to recall Bourbaki also preferring the pair-definition (as part of their general "set with a structure" paradigm.

The fact that $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ is understood, often explicitly, by almost all texts that I have. Whether or not you call it an axiom or not doesn't matter, really; fact is that it holds. The 4 axioms I mentioned distinguish a topology from many other "set plus set of subsets" structure definitions, just like the specifics of a group or a ring distinguish those structures among others of the "set with operations and constants" type. The distinguishing features are the axioms, the others (set with a set of subsets) is part of the "type declaration", if you want to use a programming metaphor. The latter struture types are purely first order, the former second order in nature, so in logic formalism there is a difference.

Comment: Is it necessary that any axiomatization of topology be second-order, or are there first-order axiomatizations?

Comment: @R.Burton: A topological space can be defined within ZFC, which is a first order theory, so the axiomatization is first order. Sets are objects, and sets of sets are still objects in standard set theory; you don’t need to go to second order.